# React Native Connect Three or More Screen using for react navigation

Tags: react-native

how to connect three or more screen in react native for Android and using react navigator.

Comment: What do you mean 'connect'? If you were trying to ask dealing with different screens and go to another screen and back, you can use StackNavigator. It's all described in the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear and and I can only assume what you want to achieve.

To be sure that we are on the same page, make sure you have run this command `npm install --save react-navigation` inside your project root directory.

Now in your `app.js` file you have to import StackNavigator from React-Navigation.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Then you should import your screen components which later can be added to StackNavigator. For the sake of this example I import random files with random names. You wanted three and more, so let's import four.

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import NewsScreen from './screens/NewsScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
```

All these files are located in the `screens` folder which itself is located in the same folder as `app.js` file. Now let's create our StackNavigator. These next lines go inside the `app.js`.

```
const NavigationApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    News: { screen: NewsScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
})
```

Now your `app.js` file should look like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import NewsScreen from './screens/NewsScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

const NavigationApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { 
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'Home'
        }
    },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen},
    News: { screen: NewsScreen},
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen}
})

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationApp />
        );
    }

}
```

Just in case to be super certain that you would get the full experience of our epic journey let's create one example screen with button which would let us navigate to another screen. Let's say it's `Home` and we have a button which would let us navigate to `Profile`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigate
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{color: 'steelblue'}} onPress={() => navigate('Profile')}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: 'white', padding: '10'}}>
                        Go to Profile screen
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you to move on with your project and I really recommend to dive into the documentations of the libraries you will be using in the future because in the long run it is very useful and helps you get better in many aspects.